# How to execute Cascading app using Eclipse on Windows

Tags: java, cascading

I have cloned the `Cascading for the Impatient` from Git Hub.

I ran the `gradle` command to create a jar file.

Without `Hadoop cluster` is it possible to run the program using Eclipse?

Do i have to set any extra configuration's to run the `Cascading` app from Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to use `LocalFlowConnector` when we run the cascading program from eclipse or using Local File System.

**Sample Code:**

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
AppProps.setApplicationJarClass(properties, TestCascading.class);
FlowConnector flowConnector = new LocalFlowConnector();
// create the source tap
FileTap inTap = new FileTap(new TextLine(), "C://Users//rain.txt");
// create the sink tap
FileTap outTap = new FileTap(new TextLine(), "C://Users//out.txt");
// specify a pipe to connect the taps
Pipe copyPipe = new Pipe("copy");
// connect the taps, pipes, etc., into a flow
FlowDef flowDef = FlowDef.flowDef().addSource(copyPipe, inTap).addTailSink(copyPipe, outTap);

// run the flow
Flow flow = flowConnector.connect(flowDef);
flow.complete();
```